# Cannot set value from getStaticPaths even though it have value

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I don't know why I can log value and i saw it have value, but when I set this value to ReactNode, it don't show anything. I just follow the docs of Nextjs.

What is my problem and how can I fix it?

my file name is [productId].tsx
My code

```
const productDetail : NextPage<Product>= (product) => {
 
  console.log(product)

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div style={{ marginTop: 200 }}>
        <div className="grid wide">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col l-12 c-12 m-12">
              <h1 className={styles.productName}>Name:{product.productName}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query<GetProductsQuery>({
    query: GetProductsDocument,
    variables: { 
      paginationOptions:{
        skip:0
      }
     },
  });

  return {
    paths: data.getProducts.products!.map((product) => ({
      params: { productId: `${product.id}` },
    })),
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
};
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<
  { [key: string]: any },
  { productId: string }
> = async ({ params }) => {
  
  const data = await client.query<GetProductQuery>({
    query: GetProductDocument,
    variables: { productId: params?.productId },
  });

  return {
    props:{
      product:data.data.getProduct.product
    }
  };
};

export default productDetail;
```

Have a nice day!

I don't know why but i fix my error by create a Props interface

```
interface Props{
  product:Product
}

const productDetail: NextPage<Props> = ({product}) => {
...
}
```

Comment: Could you double-check these two lines? `paths: data.getProducts.products` and `product:data.data.getProduct.product` - in the former snippet, you're extracting from `data` whereas in the latter, you're extracting from `data.data`. Is this correct?

Comment: i did, but if i type `data.getProduct.product` i get this error `Property 'getProduct' does not exist on type 'ApolloQueryResult<GetProductQuery>'`

Comment: oh i know why, i don't destructor it, but it not harmful.

Comment: hi Loc  you can check data in getStaticProps ! when use console log in this part , you can see log in terminal ! if everything is ok, you have log in browser

Comment: it all good. I knew why this data cannot display, i comment below my question.Thanks for help and have a nice day!